# JQuery, output a comma separated list in CSV format

Tags: jquery, html, csv

I am learning JQuery and I am having trouble trying to write code which outputs a comma separated list in a CSV format from HTML code. I am trying to put the the titles of the images in a comma separated list.

Here is the HTML I am using:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <img src="/images/title.jpg" title="TITLE IMAGE" />
      <div id="brand-container">
         <div class="xyz">
            <img src="/images/brand1.jpg" title="Adidas" />
            <img src="/images/brand2.jpg" title="Dr Martens" />
            <img src="/images/brand3.jpg" title="Fred Perry" />
            <img src="/images/brand4.jpg" title="Lacoste" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="xyz">
         <img src="/images/other.jpg" title="OTHER IMAGE" />
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

The following JQuery code is what I have tried to use.

```
var title = $(':').map(function() { 
    return this.value; 
}).get().join(',');
```

Comment: This is very vague, can you please post the data source and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sorry for being vague, I have edited the post with some code that I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple snippet, that may help you. What you should do is to store all the  elements in a variable, then iterate trough it storing the title string in some kind of object/array. Then simply stringify the results. I hope it will help you a little.

```js
var images = $('.xyz > img'),
  results = [],
  textarea = $('#csv');
$.each(images, function() {
  results.push($(this).prop('title'));
});
textarea.text(results.join());
```

```css
#csv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="/images/title.jpg" title="TITLE IMAGE" />
<div id="brand-container">
  <div class="xyz">
    <img src="/images/brand1.jpg" title="Adidas" />
    <img src="/images/brand2.jpg" title="Dr Martens" />
    <img src="/images/brand3.jpg" title="Fred Perry" />
    <img src="/images/brand4.jpg" title="Lacoste" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="xyz">
  <img src="/images/other.jpg" title="OTHER IMAGE" />
</div>

<textarea id="csv"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you, it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Do you mean to output all the image titles in your page?**

1. The `title` attribute in an `img` object is referred by $('#???').title
2. To return all image objects, use $('img').  Use `$('#brand-container img')` instead if you want to output titles within div `brand-container`;

So that's the answer:

`var title = $('img').map(function() {return this.title; }).get().join(',');`

return
`"TITLE IMAGE,Adidas,Dr Martens,Fred Perry,Lacoste,OTHER IMAGE"`